# How to get value by Key in Dictionary

Tags: c#

When I am trying to get value from the Dictionary key, it returns error

I have Tried below approach:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Credentials { get; set; }
Approach1: Credentials["Password"]
```

KeyName is correct and present in my Dictionary
[image]

[image]
It returns error

> +Credentials["0"]'Credentials["0"]' threw an exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'string
>   {System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException}

However below code worked as expected

```
Credentials.TryGetValue(Credentials.FirstOrDefault().Key, out string password);
```

I need to get value using key in dictionary for which i am getting error .

Comment: Your error makes it look like you're doing `Credentials["0"]` not `Credentials["Password"]`?

Comment: I am doing Credentials["Password"] but getting error for that

Comment: According to the screenshot it should be `Credentials["1"]["Password"]`: `Credentials["1"]` returns a dictionary `{"Password", 201900}` from which we return `201900` by `"Password"` key

Comment: What you posted isn't valid code. Dictionaries work just fine, whether you use `var result=dict[Key];` or `dict.TryGetValue(key,out var result);`. If you get that exception it means the key isn't there.

Comment: Besides the error is pretty clear - the string `0` was used instead of `Password` as the key.

Comment: Dmitry :   Credentials["1"]["Password"] gives error Credentials["1"]["Password"] error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

Comment: That screenshot would make sense if `Credentials` was a `Dictionary<string,string>[]` array, not a Dictionary<string,string>`

Comment: @Mayank which means this is an array, not a string. Post *actual* code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Mayank: then `Credentials[1]["Password"]` (if .net tries to convert `"1"` into `int` and fails, let's provide integer `1`)

Comment: @Dmistry: This is also returning same error

Comment: @Panagiotis : Credentials.GetType() returns  System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary

Comment: the screenshot is valid, this is a simple Dictionary<string, string> it looks this way in a QuickWatch

Comment: @Mayank why did you use `Credentials["1"]["Password"]` then? . Post *actual* code that compiles and reproduces the problem. I suspect you won't be able to do so, unless you use `"0"` instead of `"Password"`

Comment: "I am doing Credentials["Password"] but getting error for that" how did you test that this is the line that is throwing the exception. Your problem is not reproducible yet and your error message suggests that a different line is throwing this error

Comment: @Mong: I get the error in QuickWatch as well as in C# code

Comment: @Mayank you still haven't posted actual code. How can anyone help? You can't assume that millions of developers missed such a glaring problem for 17 years. You need only a couple of lines to create a dictionary, set two items and then try to read from it.

Comment: @Panagiotis: ok I will create a sample to create dictionary

Comment: @Mayank I already posted code that proves that Dictionary<> works. It's just 4 lines

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is simply that you're using the wrong key. If you want to know what the key is, then look **very carefully** at `Credentials.FirstOrDefault().Key`. I can't tell you what it *is* without a minimal repro, but personally, I suspect that it is a trailing white-space.

Try:

```
var key = Credentials.FirstOrDefault().Key;
Console.WriteLine("'" + key + "'");
```

the point of the surrounding quotes here being to make extra whitespace obvious. It that doesn't yield an obvious answer: you'll need to look at the actual character data (`ToCharArray()`) - there could be unicode shenanigans going on.

The key isn't `"0"`, though - that's just the index when treated as an enumerable.

Comment: Credentials.FirstOrDefault().Key returns the correct value but when I try to get value from that key, I am not able to do that

Comment: @Mayank yes you are - that is literally what you did when you said "However below code worked as expected" - so: I don't think the key is what *you* think the key is. Check **very, very carefully**.

Comment: Yes you was correct. Key has a extra space that was causing the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What the question claims can't be reproduced. It's such a basic feature that any issues would have been noticed back in 2005 when `Dictionary<>` was introduced.

```
var Credentials=new Dictionary<string,string>();
Credentials["User"]="2004";
Credentials["Password"]="201900";

Debug.Assert(Credentials["Password"]=="201900");
```

What *does* throw is this:

```
var x=Credentials["0"];
```

This will correctly throw :

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
```

Because there's no such key in the dictionary.

Perhaps there's an attempt to read the dictionary items by index? In any case the correct call would be :

```
var x=dict.ElementAt(0);
```

A dictionary's indexer *can't* be used to access items by index. In fact, a dictionary doesn't have any meaningful order. From the documentation :

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

The order *can* change as items are added to an index.

Comment: I too created sample code , for me it is also working, I need to check why this code is not working in my application

Comment: @Mayank because as everyone else has explained, the wrong key was used. Or you tried to use the dictionary as if it were an array and tried to pass `0` to get the first item.

Comment: Yes you was correct. Key has a extra space that was causing the issue. Thank you